# Java program: Problem with exception class in program to sort array in order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, exception

I've got a problem with throw my exception class, to this program. This program is working well and sort properly in order. But I want also to add there my exception class to InputMissmatchexception. I want to throw an exception when putting other value than numbers. Can anybody help me?
Code below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class metod1 {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Size, i;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter how many numbers you want to sort: ");
        Size = sc.nextInt();

        int[] a = new int[Size];

        System.out.print("Enter " + Size + " numbers which should be sorted: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(a);

        System.out.println("\nAfter sorting:  ");
        for (int Number : a) {
            System.out.print(Number + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size, i;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter how many numbers you want to sort: ");
        size = sc.nextInt();

        int[] a = new int[size];

        System.out.print("Enter " + size + " numbers which should be sorted: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            try {
                a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == size) {
            Arrays.sort(a);

            System.out.println("\nAfter sorting:  ");
            for (int number : a) {
                System.out.print(number + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample run-1:**

```
Enter how many numbers you want to sort: 3
Enter 3 numbers which should be sorted: 
10 a 30
Invalid input
```

**Sample run-2:**

```
Enter how many numbers you want to sort: 3
Enter 3 numbers which should be sorted: 
20 10 30

After sorting:  
10  20  30
```

**Notes:**

**A.** You should always follow the naming convention. Check https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html for details.

**B.** You can replace

```
System.out.println("Invalid input");
break;
```

with

```
throw new InputMismatchException("Invalid input");
```

but it will make the output look ugly e.g.

```
Enter how many numbers you want to sort: 3
Enter 3 numbers which should be sorted: 
20 a 30
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: Invalid input
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and some hints. I want to also try this but with my custom exception class.

Comment: You are most welcome. You can create your custom exception class by extending `InputMismatchException`. Feel free to comment in case you need help with that.